# vite:react-babel throwing error with Typescript ReturnType<typeof GenericConsumer<T>>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, typescript-generics, prettier

I am building an app using Vite, React, and TS. I have the following code which is causing vite to fail:

```
export type UseSearchFilters<T> = ReturnType<typeof useSearchFilters<T>>
```

It throws the following error:

```
[plugin:vite:react-babel] useSearchFilters.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (6:68)

6  |  export type UseSearchFilters<T> = ReturnType<typeof useSearchFilters<T>>
```

Specifically it is getting bugged out by the final `>`, but if I delete it, it wants it back. tsc is fine with this, but babel and prettier are not for whatever reason.

I have no idea what I could be doing to cause this, since I have seen plenty of examples of people online passing a generic to a `ReturnType<typeof GenericConsumer<T>>` with no issues. My team is totally baffled by this and it is killing the functionality.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Dependencies:

```
      "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
      "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
      "react": "^17.0.0",
      "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
      "typescript": "^4.3.2",
      "vite": "^3.0.4",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:

I needed to update `typescript` to at least 4.7 (I settled on 4.7.4), but crucially `@vitejs/plugin-react` was out of date. Updating to the latest (`2.2.0`) resolved this issue for me.
There is also an issue with Prettier not being happy with it, but at least the app builds now.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is using TypeScript version `4.3.2`.

`typeof useSearchFilters<T>` is an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions). Those were first introduced in version [`4.7`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions). That's why the build fails.

Your editor (and your global `tsc` installation) are probably using a newer TypeScript version which is why you only see the error during build.

You can check out [this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ts=4.6.4#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjAZwKYGUMEMBOUAFgGJwA2MG+aAPACoB8AFAJTIDeAvsMBgB4AHBPhjIYAT0EZkAVUw4CxMpWp0myALzIAShhhh8EelIy1J0hCFQK8hUhSo0GjRkA) and change the TypeScript version on the top-left corner to see it working with versions >= `4.7.4`.

Comment: Cool @tobias-s will give this a spin and if it works out I will mark this as the correct answer.